# IndexError: string index out of range, when comparing two strings

Tags: if-statement, indexing, printing, equivalent

My code is trying to compare each separate character in a string to find the differences between two words. However, the line "if a[i] == b [i]" appears to be giving some grief. i is a variable which has already been given a value, and will be tracked through, and I cannot see how it is not running. My code in full is as follows:

```
a = str(input("Choose a word, any word: "))
b = str(input("Choose another word: "))
j = 0
r = 0
n = len(a)
m = len(b)
if n == m:
    while r <= n:
        if a[r] == b[r]:
            r = r + 1
        else:
            j = j + 1
            r = r + 1
    print("The hamming distance between ", a, "and ", b, "is: ", j)
else:
    p = max(n, m) - min(n, m)
    while r <= p:
        if a[r] == b[r]:
            r = r + 1
        else:
            j = j + 1
        r = r + 1
    k = p + j
    print ("The hamming distance between ", a, "and ", b, "is: ", k)
```

I know it likely isnt the most compact, but any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

*Edit: I have fixed it, sheer stupidity on my part, a simple case of removing the equal from after the r <= n and r <= p parts fixed it*

Comment: Thank you for sharing your gained knowledge! You could make your findings more accessible to the community by [answering your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it, sheer stupidity on my part, a simple case of removing the equal from after the r <= n and r <= p parts fixed it.